# How to create an alias for my website and make it accessible through this alias?

Tags: drupal-7, alias, wampserver

I'm new in the Stackoverflow community!
Anyway, i'm making a site through Drupal for a project, and the site is already online to the internet. But my site is accessible only through my IP, and i want to create an alias for my IP. How can i do this?

I'm using WampServer, which has Apache, MySQL and PHP, to make my site available on the internet and to use Drupal. How can i create an alias for my site and make this alias available to the whole net?

Thanks in advance, guys! :D

Comment: Look up Dynamic DNS. I think noip.com offer one free dynamic domain name still. It will not look like a real domain name i.e. mysite.noip.com for example. Alternatively buy a real domain name and get the DNS to point to your routers WAN ip address.

Comment: Yeah, but the thing is that i am my own host, i'm configuring an Apache server and the site is online already, but can be acessed only by it's IP. I want to create an alias for my site so it can be acessed easily.

Comment: You cannot do anything locally that will be available across the internet. Ether you buy a domain name and point that at you Routers WAN IP or you get a Dynamic DNS and do the same